# Недопустимое имя столбца в запросе

Tags: c#, sql

Есть запрос, который содержит кириллические символы(думаю вся проблема в них)

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand($"Select * from [Админы] where [Номер]=@nomer", conn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomer",nomer);

SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Система пишет

```
{"Недопустимое имя столбца \"Номер\"."}
```

Запрос в ManagementStudio работает.

Comment: `Запрос в ManagementStudio работает.` покажите текст запроса, который работает + схему таблицы

Answer (score 0):

А просто **Select** работает?

```
Select * from [Админы]
```

Если да, то перепроверьте, а точно ли **[Номер]** у Вас именуется именно так.

В идеале конечно же, писать имена столбцов в транслите или на английском.